# JQ - Extract one part of a 2 part JSON

Tags: jq

Consider the below 2 part JSON.

Context: I have this JSON data from a OCI Bucket upload and I want to extract a specific part of it.

```
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": "2"
}
{
  "A": "1",
  "B": "2"
}
```

Expected output

```
{
  "a": "1",
  "b": "2"
}
```

I am interested in extracting the first part of the JSON and then get the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways to generate your output:

###### Null input

This will read the first JSON entity from the input and then terminate

```
jq -n 'input'
```

###### Slurping

This will read the full JSON input into an array and then return the first item of the array

```
jq -s 'first'
```

Comment: Your solutions blends well with my needs and has helped me close the loop. Thank you for your prompt response.